# Creating User Controls with Properties Accessible in Design Mode

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, designmode

How can I access a user controls properties from the design view?

For example, I have a custom user control called `NoteBox` with a `Title` property.

I'd like to be able to set the `Title` property thorough design view and have that show up on my form, just like you would with the `Text` property of a label, button, or groupbox.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, and it should, for the most part, just work automatically when you drag your UserControl onto a designer.  There are many attributes, such as `CategoryAttribute` and similar, that help the `PropertyGrid` determine how to display your control properties.

For details, I recommend reading [Getting the Most Out of the .NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx).  That article details all of the appropriate attributes, as well as demonstrating how to make custom editors for your properties as needed, etc.

Comment: This seems to allow me to set those properties once the application is running, but I don't see how this allows me to access those properties before I compile.

Comment: @elucid8 This is for setting them up so the Windows Forms designer works properly with them.